# flutter OneSignal send notification for multiple devices for the same user using external_id

Tags: flutter, push-notification, onesignal

I want to send the same push notification for each device of a user using onesignal flutter
I mean:

User A open the Mobile app with his First device and register a Subscription ID with custom external_id into OneSignal
User A open the Mobile app with his Second device and register a new Subscription ID with the same external_id into OneSignal.

this haw i save Subscription ID

```
 var status = await OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState();
    playerId = status?.userId!;
```

and this haw i try to send notification but i don't know haw to send notification using external_id or tags

```
  Future<void> sendNotification() async {
    try {
      await OneSignal.shared.postNotification(OSCreateNotification(
        playerIds: [playerId],
        content: "${widget.Name}",
        heading: "appname",
      ));

      print("true");
    } catch (e) {
      print("error: $e");
    }
  }
```